# Flutter RenderFlex children have non-zero flex but incoming height constraints are unbounded problem

Tags: flutter, dart

I am new to flutter and somehow I get the error RenderFlex children have non-zero flex but incoming height constraints are unbounded problem. I tried to add mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min inside Column but it does not work. I know when I remove the expanded code, it all work. But I do need expanded part to show the data in TabBarView.

Here is my code

```
@override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return new Scaffold(
      body: new Column(
        children: <Widget>[
          new ToolBar("Title"),
          new DefaultTabController(
            length: 3,
            child: new Column(
              mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
              children: <Widget>[
                new Row(
                  children: <Widget>[
                    new Expanded(
                      child: TabBar(
                        tabs: sortedGroup.map((tab) {
                          return new Tab(
                            text: tab.name,
                          );
                        }).toList()
                      )
                    ),
                  ],
                ),

                new Expanded(
                  child: new TabBarView(
                    children: sortedGroup.map((group) {
                      return new Column(
                        children: <Widget>[
                          new Text("test")
                        ],
                      );
                    }).toList(),
                  )
                )
               )
              ],
            ),
          ),
          new BottomNavigation()
        ]
      )
    );
  }
```

Answer (score 1):

This is because of how the Box Constraints are passed down by parent to a child, which is weird for Column and Row widgets.

Expanded will expand or take up the remaining available space, but ***it does so based on the BoxConstraint of the immediate Column***. **Column will pass down infinite height as constraint to its children**.

The first Column box constraints are passed down by the parent Scaffold will be dimensions of the screen but the Column ***will not pass down the same constraints to children along the main axis***.

So, the nested Column will have a finite width constraint ***but the height will have infinite height***. So, when the Expanded looks at its parent and sees that it can expand to infinite and thats when you get the error.

To fix the issue, wrap your DefaultTabController with Expanded, that will pass down a finite height constraint to the nested Column.

I have written a Medium [article](https://medium.com/@sid.310/flutter-box-constraints-101-the-basics-bd0babe650f9) series on this if you want to learn more.

Answer (score 0):

You are getting that error since you wrapped `body` with `Column` that again has a `Column` and `Expanded` as children. A `Column` widget expands to maximum vertical space and if it has `Expanded` it'll again try to gain maximum available space. 
In order to resolve this issue, just remove the parent `Column` and directly have `DefaultTabController` as a widget inside `body`. You can keep rest of the code as is. Sample working code below:

```
return new Scaffold(
      body: 
          new DefaultTabController(
            length: 3,
            child: new Column(
              mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
              children: <Widget>[
                new Row(
                  children: <Widget>[
                    new Expanded(
                      child: TabBar(
                        tabs: [Tab(icon: Icon(Icons.school, color: Colors.black),),
                  Tab(icon: Icon(Icons.home, color: Colors.black),),
                  Tab(icon: Icon(Icons.local_hospital, color: Colors.black),),]

                      )
                    ),
                  ],
                ),
                new Expanded(
                  child: new TabBarView(
                    children: [
                      new Container(
                color: Colors.redAccent,
                child: Center(child: Text('Hi from School', style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white),),),
                ),
                      new Container(
                color: Colors.redAccent,
                child: Center(child: Text('Hi from School', style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white),),),
                ),
                      new Container(
                color: Colors.redAccent,
                child: Center(child: Text('Hi from School', style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white),),),
                ),

                    ]
                  )
                )

        ]
      )

          ));
```

[image]

Hope this answers your question.